# Google Maps UIWebview

Tags: javascript, ios, html, google-maps, uiwebview

I've this script, it's works good in any browsers, but when I am using in an UIWebview, it's stopped in loading Coords, but I don't know why it's not allowed! It not loading map. What I doing wrong?

Stopped: 
pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

```
var geocoder;
    var mapDisplay, directionsService;
    var pos;
    function initialize() {
        var cli_1 = new google.maps.LatLng(26.2160476, -80.1084793);
        var cli_2 = new google.maps.LatLng(25.858509, -80.32514119999999);
        var cli_3 = new google.maps.LatLng(26.1974604, -80.09722670000001);
        var mapOptions = {
            panControl : false,
            zoomControl : true,
            mapTypeControl : false,
            mapTypeControlOptions : {
                style : google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
            },
            scaleControl : false,
            streetViewControl : false,
            overviewMapControl : false,
            draggable : true,
            disableDoubleClickZoom : true,
            scrollwheel : false,
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            zoom : 12
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position : cli_1,
            map : map,
            icon : '/img/ico_map/1.png'
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position : cli_2,
            map : map,
            icon : '/img/ico_map/2.png'
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position : cli_3,
            map : map,
            icon : '/img/ico_map/3.png'
        });
        if (navigator.geolocation) {

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

                pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position : pos,
                    map : map,
                    icon : '/img/ico_map/ponto.png'
                });
                map.setCenter(pos);
                alert(pos);
            }, function() {
                handleNoGeolocation(true);
            });
        } else {
            handleNoGeolocation(false);
        }
        var input = (document.getElementById('pac-input'));
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
        google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
            for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
                marker.setMap(null);
            }
            markers = [];
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
                var image = {
                    url : place.icon,
                    size : new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin : new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor : new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                };
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map : map,
                    icon : image,
                    title : place.name,
                    position : place.geometry.location
                });
                markers.push(marker);
                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
            var bounds = map.getBounds();
            searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
        });
    }
    function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
        if (errorFlag) {
            var content = 'Error: Servico de localizacao falhou.';
        } else {
            var content = ('Error: Servico de localizacao falhou.');
        }
        var options = {
            map : map,
            position : new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
            content : content
        };
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
        map.setCenter(options.position);
    }
    function initializeDirections() {
        alert(initializeDirections);
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var enderDe = pos;
        var enderAte = 'S Federal Hwy,1199,FL--33062   ';
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address' : enderAte,
            'region' : 'BR'
        }, trataLocs);
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        mapDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        mapDisplay.setMap(map);
        calcRota(enderDe, enderAte);
    }
    function calcRota(endDe, endPara) {
        alert(calcRota);
        var request = {
            origin : endDe,
            destination : endPara,
            travelMode : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                mapDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }
    function trataLocs(results, status) {
        alert(trataLocs);
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map : map,
                position : results[0].geometry.location
            });
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: You can get some sample [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/), and plz take look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648511/google-maps-in-uiwebview-shows-driving-directions-not-the-map-directly), it may helps.

Comment: @bjiang, thanks! But my project works in JSP, I can't change for native iOS.